# Error after installing the SPM package of Realm/SwiftLint: no such file or directory

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swift-package-manager

So I'm needing to install SwiftLint for a project and I installed it as an SPM package from their repo here: https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint.

Shortly after installing it, I go to build the project and get this error:

`/Users/MyUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-caihxbhbecuvjfdnnwkmygqurxhn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Project.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project.build/Script-89127C271F8EAAD2009335C8.sh: line 2: /SwiftLint/swiftlint: No such file or directory`

`Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`

I'm not very experienced with Packages so this is all new to me but I can't seem to find any documentation on this particular error, or if there is something else I'm missing in the installation. I've tried removing and reinstalling the package, deleting DerivedData and cleaning the build in every combination/order you can think of. Currently running Xcode 13.2.1 and a target of iOS 14.1.